# Can someone explain Happy Quinn jokes in the Scorpion episode "Crazy Train"?

Tags: scorpion

In the **Scorpion** TV series season 2 episode 7 ***"Crazy Train"*** , Happy Quinn tells a number of jokes to bunch of people at a club in the end. As I understood those are jokes to a geek or "special people". Unfortunately I didn't understand those jokes?

Can anyone explain those jokes, what I mean is how those are jokes?

Comment: Down votes are unwarranted *smh*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basic puns, word-play jokes, based on math, chemistry, and physics.

> Knock, knock! *Who's there?* Matthew. *Matthew who?* **"Math-you"** could never do unless you had an IQ of 184.

Math is hard. Unless your really smart.

> Ammonia and sodium hypochlorite hook up at a bar. Everyone inside dies.

Sodium Hypochlorite is in most houses. It's called Chlorine Bleach. Mix it with Ammonia and you get Chlorine Gas. And Die. **(For real, it's dangerous. Says so right on the bottle. Also don't mix Chlorine with Vinegar or basically any other cleaner. It's dangerous to clean a house right!)**

> I've been reading this great book on antigravity. I can't put it down.

Gravity, putting things down, I get it. It's a double entendre.

> I have this new theory on inertia, but it's not gaining any momentum.

Inertia and Momentum are two basic properties of an object. `An object at rest stays at rest and an object in motion stays in motion with the same speed and in the same direction unless acted upon by an unbalanced force.` as stated in Newton's First Law of Motion. Inertia is what keeps things not moving, from not moving, unless you add energy (I.E. Momentum). [Here's Newton's First Law for Dummies.](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/physics-understanding-newtons-first-law-of-motion.html)

Comment: Lol, nice jokes and answer too +1